# Is my understanding of the following variable scope correct

Tags: javascript

I am currently in the process of learning Javascript.

I came up with the following code sample

```
var gc = "From Global";

var mp = {
    gc    : "Inside mp",
    funct : function(){
        console.log( gc);        //Calls global instead of local
    }
}

var ft = function() {
    gc    = "Inside Function";
    this.funct = function(){
        console.log(gc);       //Calls locally declared variable

    }
}

mp.funct();           //calls gc from global scope      --->A
var inst = new ft();  
inst.funct();         //calls gc from its local scope   --->B
```

I wanted to know why statement A prints the value of the global variable while statement B prints the value of its locally scoped variable. I am told that it has to do with the fact that statement B creates an instance of ft and its context is ft while statement A context is the window and the local variable of global local window is the gc gloable . Is that correct ? If so then I am confused with what context is  I was under the impression that

```
foo.bar() ; //Here foo is the context
m.j;        //Here m is the context
```

How can window be the context of `mp.funct()`

Comment: Both `funct`s refer to the same global variable. You just change its value in `ft()`.

Comment: in `ft` the variable `gc` is not defined locally, it still refers to the global one, because there is no `var` that binds `gc` to the scope of the `ft` function.

Comment: Dont know why the -1 vote ? Seems to me like a genuine question

Comment: Short answer: because it's not a this just a closure behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example:

```
var mp = {
    gc    : "Inside mp",
    funct : function(){
        console.log( gc);        //Calls global instead of local
    }
}
```

You would have to call `this.gc`, since an object member (a key value pair) is not a variable, but a member of the object.

In this example:

```
var ft = function() {
    gc    = "Inside Function";
    this.funct = function(){
        console.log(gc);

    }
}
```

`gc` is *not* an object member, and overrides the global variable that you set. Therefore you can just log `gc` and get the expected value.

You could also declare a locally scoped variable:

```
var ft = function() {
    var somethingLocal    = "I am local";
    this.funct = function(){
        console.log(somethingLocal); // Calls locally declared variable

    }
}
```

Comment: `gc` is not locally scoped it is global.

Answer (score 0):

A quote from MDN [JavaScript Scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bzt2dkta%28v=vs.94%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> JavaScript has two scopes: global and local. A variable that is
>   declared **outside a function** definition is a global variable, and its
>   value is accessible and modifiable throughout your program. A variable
>   that is declared inside a function definition is local. It is created
>   and destroyed every time the function is executed, and it cannot be
>   accessed by any code outside the function. JavaScript does not support
>   block scope (in which a set of braces {. . .} defines a new scope),
>   except in the special case of block-scoped variables.

In your code, the `mp` is defined in global scope, outside function `ft`. When you call the function defined inside `mp`, member `funct` will not "see" the other member in the same object. What it can see is the context that `mp` is in.

While you do the same thing inside `ft`, `gc = "Inside...";` is changing the global variable `gc`. So when you use `gc`, it is acutually using that one in global scope.

**EDIT**

Thanks @t.niese for pointing one mistake that `gc` is not defined locally. Just modified.

Comment: `gc` is not defined locally in the function. `gc    = "Inside Function";` sets the global `gc` to `"Inside Function"`  because there is not `var` binding `gc` to the scope of the function.

Answer (score -1):

"mp" is a Javascript Object while "ft" is a Function.  That is the difference.

mp.gc and mp.funct are "keys" within the Javascript object, not variables.  If you wanted mp to use mp.gc you could do:

```
var mp = {
    gc    : "Inside mp",         // not a variable by itself, only a variable if used as mp.gc
    funct : function(){
        console.log( this.gc);   //Calls "local" now
    }
}
```

Comment: `mp` is a javascript Object and not a JSON representation. Not only because `gc` and `funct` don't have double quotes, but also because in JavaScript JSON is always a string.